# Transform ConcurrentHashMap into a sorted list in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

In Java8, after computing the data in `ConcurrentHashMap`,

```
// this is a working code, which I want to simplify
ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> data =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
// ... (fill in the data object)
final int l = data.keySet().size();
P[] points = new P[l];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : data.entrySet())
    points[i++] = new A(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get() * 1.0 / 105);
Arrays.sort(points);
```

I want to achieve this:

```
data.parallelStream()
.map( (k, v) -> new A(k, v.get() * 1.0 / 105) )
.sort().forEach(System.out::println)
```

How to do that properly?

Comment: You should probably check if you really need AtomicInteger as value type in an already concurrent Map implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You need to create a `Stream` of `Entry` objects, so you can't write `(k, v)->`.

```
data.entrySet()
    .parallelStream()
    .map(e -> new A(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get() * 1.0 / 105))
    .sorted()
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I would feel bad to just edit my answer while yours was correct at first to keep my upvotes so I deleted and upvoted yours.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard You are still the best :)

Comment: @StephanRozinsky Actually I completely failed this answer, even my original one was full of typos which someone else (thanks to him) fixed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thanks. I posted this version while your original was still there, so this wasn't just a rip off. I find it odd that other people can edit your answers. If someone edits my answer and as a consequence I get loads of upvotes/downvotes is there anything I can do?

Comment: @pbabcdefp If you think the edit is bad, then you can rollback it. Else if it is good, then simply enjoy the upvotes :).